# content management system for non-profit

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, umbraco

I need to create a website for a non-profit that will need the following functionality along with the basic page editing and creation (hopefully a free solution)
- Newsletter
- Event Listing + integration with Google Calendar
- Possibly integration with system like guestlistapp to collect payments for Event Tickets
- Membership management system + collect payments
- Paypal Donations

I have looked at Umbraco but doesn't seem to have any of these plugins.  Please suggest other systems that you may have used in the past and can be a good fit for this scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Umbraco doesn't come out-of-the box with those plugins, but there are 'packages' available for  some of those things, and with some custom code it could do all of those things -

For example, here is a newsletter addin:
http://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/newsletter

A membership addin:
http://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/membership-system

A paypal addin:
http://our.umbraco.org/projects/paypal-ipn

An events calendar:
http://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/pdcalendar

Bottomline however is that with all of these packages, its not just a simple install and give to the client, they may require customization on your part so perhaps your client would be better-off with an off-the-shelf non-profit management package if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for this excellent response.  I received another response which is equally good.  This gives me a direction to research further.  Thank you again!

Answer (score 4):

Would recommend Joomla 2.5.6 for this.

JomSocial have a package that comes with a paid membership system which costs $268. As well as the membership system, I assume you are aware that JomSocial is a very big extension and wtih the right add-ons, will be able to perform many tasks. Take a look here:

http://www.jomsocial.com/package/

A free solution for paid membership could be [Akeeba Subscriptions](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/e-commerce/membership-a-subscriptions/19528?qh=YToxOntpOjA7czo2OiJha2VlYmEiO30=) which is a very flexible component and integrated with lots of other extensions.

For donations, take a look at the category on JED here:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/e-commerce/donations

For events and news letters, I would probably recommend using [JEvents](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/calendars-a-events/events/events-calendars/95?qh=YToyOntpOjA7czo3OiJqZXZlbnRzIjtpOjE7czo5OiJqZXZlbnRzJ3MiO30=) and 
[JNews](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/content-sharing/newsletter/11585?qh=YToyOntpOjA7czoxMDoibmV3c2xldHRlciI7aToxO3M6MTE6Im5ld3NsZXR0ZXJzIjt9) which are both free.

As for a Google Calendar, check out [GCalendar](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/calendars-a-events/events/events-calendars/1625), which is also free.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for this excellent response. I received another response which is equally good. This gives me a direction to research further. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you look at the "open source cms market share report", which is published every November and is very useful in determining which CMSs are dominant, which are growing and which are fading.  For example Joomla is a dominant player, Umbraco is a growing player.

[open source cms market share report 2011](http://www.waterandstone.com/book/2011-open-source-cms-market-share-report)

> The 2011 Open Source CMS Market Share Report concludes that three
>   brands - Joomla!, WordPress, and Drupal - dominate today’s market. The
>   Report concludes that WordPress leads in brand strength and market
>   share after a strong year.
>
> The Report follows the market share and brand strength indicators for
>   20 top systems, assessing each on a wide variety of measures. The
>   study focuses on identifying the market leaders, both in terms of rate
>   of adoption and mindshare.
>
> While WordPress, Joomla! and Drupal lead the survey set across a wide
>   range of measures, the report also identifies other trends in this
>   year's open source CMS market.
>
> ** DotNetNuke continues to lead the .NET CMS race, though Umbraco shows strength.
>
> ** Liferay & Alfresco are neck and neck in the Java CMS race.
>
> ** Concrete5 turns in an exceptional year.

[open source cms market share report 2010](http://www.waterandstone.com/book/2010-open-source-cms-market-share-report)